# Where is the parseTime() function defined?

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

I'm trying to use the code from this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/lenyy/2e0u7u3k/

At several places it calls `me.parseTime()`, but I can't figure out where that function is defined. I'm guessing it's part of Chart.js helpers or something?

Where is parseTime defined?

Comment: The `me` variable is set with `this` which refers to the object in which `determineDataLimits` is added (`extend` function).